Factors of $X^n-a$ in $K[X]$
Let $K$ be a field of positive characteristic. Let $a\neq 0,1$ in $K$. Assume that $X^n-a=f(X)g(X)$. Then we can find $d$ maximal such that $f=f_1(X^d)$ and $g=g_1(X^d)$.
Is true that the coefficient of $X$ in $f_1$ or $g_1$ is nonzero (i.e., $f_1'(0)\neq 0$ or $g_1'(0)\neq 0$) ?

The restriction $a\neq1$ is quite unnatural, as the case $a\neq0$ reduces to the case $a=1$ after extending $K$ by an $n$-th root of $a$:
Suppose that $a\in K$ is nonzero and that $X^n-a=fg$ for some $f,g\in K[X]$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $X^n-a$ in some extension $L/K$. Let $m:=\deg f$ and $n:=\deg g$, and set
$$F:=\alpha^{-m}f(\alpha X)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad G:=\alpha^{-n}g(\alpha X).$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
F(X)G(X)
&=&\alpha^{-m}f(\alpha X)\alpha^{-n}g(\alpha X)\\
&=&\alpha^{-(m+n)}f(\alpha X)g(\alpha X)\\
&=&a^{-1}\left((\alpha X)^n-a\right)\\
&=&\alpha^{-1}(aX^n-a)\\
&=&X^n-1.
\end{eqnarray}
So it suffices to find a counterexample with $a=1$. And we have $X^{12}-1=fg$ with
\begin{eqnarray}
f&:=&X^5+X^3-X^2-1\\
g&:=&X^7-X^5+X^4+X^3-X^2+1.
\end{eqnarray}

Earlier counterexample; we also have $X^{30}-1=fg$ with
\begin{eqnarray}
f&:=&X^6+X^4+X^3+X^2+1,\\
g&:=&X^{24}-X^{22}-X^{21}+2X^{19}+X^{18}-X^{17}-2X^{16}-X^{15}+2X^{14}+2X^{13}\\
&\ &-2X^{11}-2X^{10}+X^9+2X^8+X^7-X^7-2X^5+X^3+X^2-1.
\end{eqnarray}
